# <pre> text wrapping when no need

Tags: html, css

I have a panel 'mock-up' on a webpage contained within a <div> and a <pre> tag thus:-

```
<div style="max-width:85ch;">
<pre style="background-color:#0D0D0D;color:Lime;">
...
</pre></div>
```

The maximum number of characters on any line within these tags is 80 characters, and the max-width is set to 85ch.

What could cause such text to wrap at a point which is not a line break when the web page is wide enough not to force a wrap?

[image: Example of wrapping]

FYI - it's supposed to look this this:-
[image: What it is supposed to look like]

I thought maybe the failing example was due to the user setting their fonts bigger (using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>) but it still behaves perfectly when I do that, and only wraps when the size of the browser window is no longer big enough to hold it.

Supplementary question (which might have the same answer). Is there a way to stop it wrapping ever, i.e. even when the size of the web browser is not big enough to contain it?

Comment: Have you tried using `white-space: nowrap;` in your CSS?

Comment: @konalion - I did not try using nowrap because my understanding of it was "Sequences of whitespace will collapse into a single whitespace. Text will never wrap to the next line." and I didn't want the first half of that. I just tried it right now and it concatenated all my lines onto one line and removed all the extra spaces so I definitely don't want it! Just tried white-space: pre; however, and I was surprised it actually made a difference. It seems to be the answer to my question. Unsure why white-space: pre; is not the default for a <pre> tag

Comment: I'm not repro'ing the breaking of the "Complete fields. Then press Enter". Mind sharing all of the code for this screen alone in jsbin.com? My suspicion is that you'll want white-space: pre, but that's hard to know without seeing the sequence of whitespace within your code. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/text.html#white-space-prop

Comment: I believe I have found the problem thanks to the various hints you guys have provided. I found that the default style for pre included white-space:pre-line, and when I made a new class for this that used white-space:pre, it worked.

Comment: Also, I want to thank @Justin for introducing me to the <kdb> tags (which he used in his edit of my question). I had not been aware of their existence until now! Amazing what you learn on SO!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try on the style of the `<pre>` item `white-space: pre;`, or item `white-space: pre-line;`

Comment: Thanks @DDan. I'm going to accept your answer - my problem was that I had white-space: pre-line; in the CSS for pre. When I made a new class for my panel with white-space: pre; it all worked as I expected it to.

Answer (score 0):

This is a side effect either of variance between the fonts of the parent and child or of the ways that either the browser or some additional CSS you're using renders the `pre` element. There are a number of possible causes, but the simplest solution is to set the `max-width` on `pre` itself and not on the containing `div`.

```
<div style="width: fit-content;">
    <pre style="background-color: #0D0D0D; color:Lime; max-width:85ch;">
        ...
    </pre>
</div>
```

When you set `max-width` to a font-based measure, you're using the font specified for or inherited by that element. When you inspect your elements, you'll probably find something like the following among the computer values:

```
div {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
pre {
    font-family: monospace;
}
```

The 85 character max-width means the width of the `0` character in whichever font (here, sans-serif) is set for that element. Since the font for `pre` is different, its `0` character is of a different width. The containing parent is too narrow, so the child wraps.

If you need the div to collapse to the width of the child, you can set it's width it `fit-content` or depending on the context, you can usually get away with `display: inline-block`.

If it's not caused by CSS you've written, it could be something like a CSS reset or Normalize.css, which attempts to correct for the way browsers vary in rendering the size of `pre` by using an odd and never-well-explained hack of setting `pre` to `font-family: monospace, monospace`.

Again, the simplest solution is that mentioned above, setting the font-based max-width on the `pre` element itself.

Comment: Thanks @denmch, that may solve my unasked question - i.e. the reason I use max-width:85ch when I have a maximum of 80 characters in each line. Cheers!